# Is there an equivalent of iso files for sd cards?

Tags: iso-image, sd-card

So that you can have a digital sd card just like an iso file which you can then mount e.g. using daemon tools? In order to simulate that there is physical a sd card mounted in a reader.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. First of all, you can store an ISO file on an SD card for daemon tools to load it ans fake an optical drive. Then, if what you want to fake is an SD/MMC controller (with a card inserted), ISO has nothing to do with that, and really it isn't about the file, but whether there's a software does such emulation. If you question is about attaching a disk image to a system, there's e.g. `losetup` on Linux, and on Windows you'll need to create an VHD(X), either from scratch or dump from a drive (or convert from a raw image).

Comment: An iso file is equivalent to an image file of a (disk) drive. (Note that optical media, like floppies, do not have a partition table.) But since (disk) drives typically have a partition table, you cannot mount the full drive (or the image file of such a drive).  You can only mount a drive partition (or an image file of such a partition) that contains a valid filesystem. Beware, MS Windows allows formatting of a *blank* SD card to have no partition table, whereas Linux expects you to install one.

Comment: More precisely, an ISO file is an image file that consists of a ISO9660 filesystem. It's just that people have been abusing the term / extension name when they talk about raw images of a drive / that contain other filesystems (including but not limited to UDF).

Comment: Just a dd type, sector-by-sector image would do, no?

Answer (score 0):

Treat an SD, XD, or μSD card just like any USB flash device. Many computers will boot directly from those cards, if they have a card slot built in, or will if placed in a USB card reader. For example, use [Rufus to install Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) on a card, and then boot from that. In other words, one can store the whole OS (and even read and write data and *modify* applications and the OS, for a [live OS with *persistence*](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/)) in a μSD card!

That said, *some* cards may not work well for booting, and *some* PC's may not accept them for boot devices, though by-and-large, I find they work well. Also, don't expect a persistent OS to work well from any but the fastest cards --- *writing* to flash can be far slower than to HDD.